# Pmf of Three Point distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ be a sample from a three point distribution:

$$P(X=y_1)=\frac{1-\theta}{2}$$
$$P(X=y_2)=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$P(X=y_3)=\frac{\theta}{2}$$

where $0<\theta<1$

Then I believe that the pmf of this is distribution is $\frac{n!}{y_1!y_2!y_3!}(\frac{1-\theta}{2})^{y_1}(\frac{1}{2})^{y_2}(\frac{\theta}{2})^{y_3}$

This is part of a question I'm working on where this is the first part, so I want to make sure this is right.  Am I correct in my pmf?  Thanks

Comment: The pmf is already given, why do you calculate it again?

Comment: @JimmyR. Maybe as a joint pmf.  I need to calculate a lower bound of variance for an unbiased estimator using the Cramer Rao inequality, and in that inequality I'm not sure which pmf to use, so I thought I would try to make it the joint pmf.

Comment: Ok, yes, sorry, as a joint pdf it makes sense (however I did not check it, to see if it is correct).

Comment: @JimmyR. if it is a multinomial distribution then it should be good

Comment: For example, say $n=3$ then $P(X_1=y_1,X_2=y_2,X_3=y_2)=\frac{1-θ}{2}\cdot \frac1{2}^2$, but I do not see how the factorials come in play. I do not think that this is multinomial.

Comment: From the given information, you just need to multiply the marginal pmfs together to obtain the joint pmf, just as what Jimmy did in above, and you will not have the factorials. You will have the factorials, when the question is only given the sufficient statistics - the number of samples occured in each point, and you will need to invoke the multinomial pmf. Anyway, the factorial is not necessary, and should not hinder you from further calculation.

Answer (score 0):

One way to comes formular to binomial distribution:

Throw a three face dice (The color of faces are Red, White, Blank) n times. We need to know the probability of distribution Red face in i times, White in j times, and Black in k times, and i + j + k = n. The 3 faces are biased. So $P(Red) = \frac{1-\theta}{2}$, $P(White) = \frac{1}{2}$, $P(Black) = \frac{1+\theta}{2}$.
Let X the random vaiable representing outcomes of n throws.
$$P(X =\{i\,red\,faces, j\,white\,faces, k\,blank\,faces\}) = \frac{n!}{i!j!k!}(\frac{1-\theta}{2})^{i}(\frac{1}{2})^{j}(\frac{\theta}{2})^{k}$$